# Как средствами windows 10 снизить максимальный заряд батареи ноутбука

Tags: windows-10, ноутбук

Для ноутов lenovo есть такая утилита lenovo power manager, которая позволяет ограничить максимальный уровень заряда аккумулятора до 60%. Утилита работает только под windows 7. Очень полезная штука, когда ноутбук используется вместо домашнего и постоянно подключен к сети, она позволяет увеличить срок службы аккумулятора.

Эта утилита не хочет работать на windows 10.

Подскажите пожалуйста, что можно сделать, может кто знает, может в биосе есть соответствующий пункт?
Или возможно средствами самой windows можно как то ограничить максимальный заряд?

Comment: в режиме энэргосбережения есть выпадающий список - в котором можно выбрать  с какого уровня заряда начинать подзаряжать ...и так же максимальный заряд - это было вмоём паккард бел в его фирменной утилите